# Is there a way to play the default Twilio beep sound on loop while Recording?

Tags: twilio

I have a recording application that requires the user be informed that they are being recorded. To do this, I want to play the default Twilio beep sound every 30 seconds. Is there a way I can do this such that I can continue to record audio seamlessly without the interruption of the beep or a missing section of audio on the recording?